# Using a string as a dictionary key?

Tags: python

I have a string like so:

```
string = "abc"
```

my dictionary will have a key for every letter and number in the alphabet:

```
letters = {"a" : "Ayeee", "b" : "Beeee", "c" : "Seee"}
```

how do I use the letters within the string as a key to print my dictionary so the end result will be similar to:

```
print(letters["a"], letters["b"])
```

output: Ayeee Beeee

but I want to be able to take in a string of any length, and I don't want to use loops.

The only thing I could think of is converting the string to a list, but then I really don't know what to do from there.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is the point from accessing the dict keys from external string?

Comment: What, *exactly* are you trying to do? Why don't you want to use loops?

Comment: You don't want to use loops? If it's a string of arbitrary characters, how will you learn what character you're trying to find without a loop?

Comment: @Jarad  Its a school assignment, and they told us we're not allowed to use loops, which is why Im having trouble with this assignment...

Comment: Can you share the exact text of the assignment?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ^

Comment: @mkreiger1 https://gyazo.com/0e32dfda3c78b120d0f8f151ed80a21a

our dictionary is gonna have a key for each letter of the alphabet and the value of some sort of ascii art of my choice, so I basically need to take an input and print it from my dictionary in ascii art, but I can't use loops.

Comment: What you've linked doesn't say that you are not allowed to use loops.

Comment: @mkrieger1 they told is verbally in class.

Comment: I think you've kind of misunderstood that. This task definitely involves *some sort* of loop (even if doesn't explicitly have to be a `for x in y` loop).

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your tutor again to clarify what exactly you are allowed to use and what not.

Comment: @mkrieger1 yeah I think I'll go in today and talk to the professor and get some clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
string = "abc"
letters = {"a" : "Ayeee", "b" : "Beeee", "c" : "Seee"}
#print(letters["a"], letters["b"])
for i in string:
    print letters.get(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string = "abc"
letters = {"a" : "Ayeee", "b" : "Beeee", "c" : "Seee"}

stringList = list(string)

def print_banner(string, orientation):

    #" " for horizontal
    #"\n" for vertical
    result = list(map(lambda elem: letters.get(elem), stringList))
    print(orientation.join(result))
    print()


print_banner(string, " ")
print_banner(string, "\n")
```

The output is:

```
Ayeee Beeee Seee

Ayeee
Beeee
Seee
```

Answer (score -1):

**Index the string:**

```
string = "abc"
letters = {"a" : "Ayeee", "b" : "Beeee", "c" : "Seee"}
print(letters[string[0]], letters[string[1]])
```

[image]

Comment: The question says *able to take in a string of any length*. This would require the OP to type it out for every character, but given the string could be any length, taking the index of `string[1]` has potential to throw errors